# Python : Checking if a multithreaded process has ended

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I've written a program which runs two functions simultaneously. I need to stop one of the functions when the other one ends.
I've used multiprocessing.
How do I check if the method has ended?

Comment: set some variable equal to true, and make the other function to stop when this variable becomes true.

Comment: That would work for `multithreading` because threads share memory, but it wouldn't work for `multiprocessing`.  If you used `multiprocessing`, you would need to use one of the module's classes that allows communication between processes.

Comment: Can you post some code that reflects your use? There are a lot of ways this can be achieved but it would greatly depend on your use case. Also, it seems that you're confusing multithreading and multiprocessing - those two are very different beasts in Python.

Comment: How about using events?

Comment: Communications between threads looks like this http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch12.html#_problem_199 You can use threads in your case or implement same logic for processes.